# Create RegExps on the fly using string variables

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I wanted to make the following re-usable:

```
function replace_foo(target, replacement) {
   return target.replace("string_to_replace",replacement);
}
```

I might do something like this:

```
function replace_foo(target, string_to_replace, replacement) {
   return target.replace(string_to_replace,replacement);
}
```

With string literals this is easy enough. But what if I want to get a little more tricky with the regex? For example, say I want to replace everything *but* `string_to_replace`. Instinctually I would try to extend the above by doing something like:

```
function replace_foo(target, string_to_replace, replacement) {
   return target.replace(/^string_to_replace/,replacement);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. My guess is that it thinks `string_to_replace` is a string literal, rather than a variable representing a string. Is it possible to create JavaScript regexes on the fly using string variables? Something like this would be great if at all possible:

```
function replace_foo(target, string_to_replace, replacement) {
   var regex = "/^" + string_to_replace + "/";
   return target.replace(regex,replacement);
}
```

Answer (score 230, accepted):

There's `new RegExp(string, flags)` where `flags` are `g` or `i`. So

```
'GODzilla'.replace( new RegExp('god', 'i'), '' )
```

evaluates to

```
zilla
```

Comment: And omit the `/` regex delimiters when using this form too.

Answer (score 118):

> With string literals this is easy enough.

Not really! The example only replaces the *first* occurrence of `string_to_replace`. More commonly you want to replace all occurrences, in which case, you have to convert the string into a global (`/.../g`) RegExp. You can do this from a string using the `new RegExp` constructor:

```
new RegExp(string_to_replace, 'g')
```

The problem with this is that any regex-special characters in the string literal will behave in their special ways instead of being normal characters. You would have to backslash-escape them to fix that. Unfortunately, there's not a built-in function to do this for you, so here's one you can use:

```
function escapeRegExp(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
}
```

Note also that when you use a RegExp in `replace()`, the replacement string now has a special character too, `$`. This must also be escaped if you want to have a literal `$` in your replacement text!

```
function escapeSubstitute(s) {
    return s.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
}
```

(Four `$`s because that is itself a replacement string—argh!)

Now you can implement global string replacement with RegExp:

```
function replace_foo(target, string_to_replace, replacement) {
    var relit= escapeRegExp(string_to_replace);
    var sub= escapeSubstitute(replacement);
    var re= new RegExp(relit, 'g');
    return target.replace(re, sub);
}
```

What a pain. Luckily if all you want to do is a straight string replace with no additional parts of regex, there is a quicker way:

```
s.split(string_to_replace).join(replacement)
```

...and that's all. This is a commonly-understood idiom.

> say I want to replace everything but string_to_replace

What does that mean, you want to replace all stretches of text not taking part in a match against the string? A replacement with `^` certainly doesn't this, because `^` means a start-of-string token, not a negation. `^` is only a negation in `[]` character groups. There are also negative lookaheads `(?!...)`, but there are problems with that in JScript so you should generally avoid it.

You might try matching ‘everything up to’ the string, and using a function to discard any empty stretch between matching strings:

```
var re= new RegExp('(.*)($|'+escapeRegExp(string_to_find)+')')
return target.replace(re, function(match) {
    return match[1]===''? match[2] : replacement+match[2];
});
```

Here, again, a split might be simpler:

```
var parts= target.split(string_to_match);
for (var i= parts.length; i-->0;)
    if (parts[i]!=='')
        parts[i]= replacement;
return parts.join(string_to_match);
```

Answer (score 15):

As the others have said, use `new RegExp(pattern, flags)` to do this.  It is worth noting that you will be passing string literals into this constructor, so every backslash will have to be escaped.  If, for instance you wanted your regex to match a backslash, you would need to say `new RegExp('\\\\')`, whereas the regex literal would only need to be `/\\/`. Depending on how you intend to use this, you should be wary of passing user input to such a function without adequate preprocessing (escaping special characters, etc.)  Without this, your users may get some very unexpected results.

Comment: This answer, while not the most detailed, does mention a **crucial** detail which I was just stuck on for an hour: escape any special sequences. For example, I was searching for a word starting with a certain term, so the regex I'd need is `/\b[term]\B/`, but when constructing it I need to call `new RegExp("\\b"+ term + "\\B")`. Small but important difference, and hard to spot since using it as a regex directly **does** work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

```
function replace_foo(target, string_to_replace, replacement) {
   var regex = new RegExp("^" + string_to_replace);
   return target.replace(regex, replacement);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A really simple solution to this is this:

```
function replace(target, string_to_replace, replacement) {
  return target.split(string_to_replace).join(replacement);
}
```

No need for Regexes at all

It also seems to be the fastest on modern browsers https://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall

Answer (score 1):

I think I have very good example for highlight text in string (it finds not looking at register but highlighted using register)

```
function getHighlightedText(basicString, filterString) {

    if ((basicString === "") || (basicString === null) || (filterString === "") || (filterString === null)) return basicString;

    return basicString.replace(new RegExp(filterString.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\\\$&'), 'gi'),
        function(match)
            {return "<mark>"+match+"</mark>"});

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdbzL/1258/