# Can I color certain words in Google Document using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to highlight certain words in my Google Document. I know I can replace text using document.replace, but it only replaces string itself, not formatting. Is there a way to replace string with colored string using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a better solution:

```
function highlightTextTwo() {
  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById('<your document id');
  var textToHighlight = 'dusty death';
  var highlightStyle = {};
  highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#FF0000';
  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  var textLocation = {};
  var i;

  for (i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
    textLocation = paras[i].findText(textToHighlight);
    if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {
      textLocation.getElement().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle);
    }
  }
}
```

**Previous Answer:**

The key is to being able to reference just the words you want to color.

My solution is to:

Get the text of the paragraph that contains the words you wish to color, remove the original paragraph, then add each part of the text back. As you add each part back the appendText returns a reference to just the text added, you then can specify its color with setForegroundColor():

```
function highlightText() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('<your document id>');
  var textToHighlight = 'dusty death';
  var textLength = textToHighlight.length;
  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  var paraText = '';
  var start;
  for (var i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
    paraText = paras[i].getText();
    start = paraText.indexOf(textToHighlight);
    if (start >= 0) {
      var preText = paraText.substr(0, start);
      var text = paraText.substr(start, textLength);
      var postText = paraText.substr(start + textLength, paraText.length);
      doc.removeChild(paras[i]);
      var newPara = doc.insertParagraph(i, preText);
      newPara.appendText(text).setForegroundColor('#FF0000');
      newPara.appendText(postText).setForegroundColor('#000000');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. How would you deal with word occurring more than once in the paragraph?

Comment: The same concept applies. You take the paragraph apart and reassemble it. As you reassemble it, you use setForegroudColor on each word.

Answer (score 20):

With the introduction of document-bound scripts, it's now possible to make a text highlighting function that's invoked from a custom menu.

Surely ***THIS*** is the best answer now!  8^)

This script was modified from the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581090/how-to-find-a-word-in-a-document-and-insert-a-url/16922406#16922406), and may be called from the UI (with no parameters) or a script.

```
/**
 * Find all matches of target text in current document, and highlight them.
 *
 * @param {String} target     (Optional) The text or regex to search for. 
 *                            See Body.findText() for details.
 * @param {String} background (Optional) The desired highlight color.
 *                            A default orange is provided.
 */
function highlightText(target,background) {
  // If no search parameter was provided, ask for one
  if (arguments.length == 0) {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    var result = ui.prompt('Text Highlighter',
      'Enter text to highlight:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    // Exit if user hit Cancel.
    if (result.getSelectedButton() !== ui.Button.OK) return;
    // else
    target = result.getResponseText();
  }
  var background = background || '#F3E2A9';  // default color is light orangish.
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target);

  while (searchResult !== null) {
    var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
    var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();

    //Logger.log(url);
    thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),background);

    // search for next match
    searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target, searchResult);
  }
}

/**
 * Create custom menu when document is opened.
 */
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom')
      .addItem('Text Highlighter', 'highlightText')

      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Yes, findText() works with RegEx for the `searchpattern`. In the answer, we're getting a string input from user, so you'd need to generate a RegEx from that; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371565).

Comment: Nice answer... but isn't the question about "ForeGround" color? ;) doesn't look hard to extrapolate from there though.

Comment: This is so awesome. I adapted it for my purposes. My UI menu doesn't prompt for a word to highlight and instead calls a wrapper function that has a whole list of words, and that function calls `highlightText` for each, and `highlightText` now has a counter that returns how many words were highlighted, and my wrapper sums them all up and shows them in an alert. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's possible with the method setBackgroundColor of class Text in DocumentApp : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_text#setBackgroundColor

You'll have to retrieve your words as Text elements. In order to do that you can use the find method of your object Document, then to iterate over the search results and use [getElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_searchresult#getElement). Finally, to convert your Element object into a Text object, you can use `asText()`.

Hope it'll work ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is available as a Google docs add-on named Multi-instance Text Highlighting. Hints: At first it didn't seem to work, but I closed my doc and re-opened it, and then it worked. Then it didn't seem to work now and then, but I found out that special characters in your text string can break it; I think I had a + in my string and it just didn't do anything. But without special characters, it works great. Really helped me out.

Comment: Can Multi-instance Text Highlight be used from Google Apps Script? The question was about automated coloring and I could not find a developer interface for this add-on.