# Method findText() stuck in first paragraph of Google Document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to find certain words in a Google Document, in order to format them via script. The problem is, it seems like findText() is only able to find the word, when it's in the first paragraph. If it's somewhere else, findText() will go nuts and give me (seemingly) random locations for the word. Here is how it's coded:

```
function findBoldMarks(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('docId');
  var docText = doc.editAsText();

  // search initial bold markup 
  var srcB0 = body.findText('bold0');
  var idB0 = srcB0.getStartOffset();

  // search final bold markup 
  var srcB1 = body.findText('bold1');
  var idB1End = srcB1.getEndOffsetInclusive();

  // set markup and text wrapped within bold markup as bold
  docText.setBold(idB0, idB1End, true);
}
```

I feel like I must be ignoring something basic here, but after hours struggling with it, I'm not sure anymore. I appreciate any thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you not just manually hit the bold icon instead of typing in these bold word tags or are those being inserted by a script before hand?

Comment: Yes - I'll be generating the document multiple times, programmatically, from a spreadsheet as a database. I've tried the mail merge approach, but unfortunately the data structure that I have doesn't allow me to format the words that way.

Answer (score 0):

To continue searching past the first occurrence, you'll need to wrap the search in loop and provide the second "from" argument in [findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text?hl=en#findText%28String,SearchResult%29).

Here's the start of an example that only searches for 1 word...

```
function findBoldMarks(){
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var pattern = "bold0";
  var searchResult = body.findText(pattern);
  var style = {};

  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  while (searchResult !== null) {
    var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
    var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();

    thisElementText.setAttributes(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),style);

    // search for next match
    searchResult = body.findText(pattern, searchResult);
  }
}
```

...derived from some answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064972/can-i-color-certain-words-in-google-document-using-google-script).

Maybe some one can modify to include the text between the two search terms.  It doesn't appear that `findText()` accepts a regular expression search pattern, so another approach may be needed to do that.

Comment: I only wanted to comment that, in order to keep formatting through the text, I've set the function to delete the markups after formatted, then created a while loop searching for the same markups over and over again, until all markups were deleted. It worked! Regarding the search being constrained to the first paragraph, it's still an issue. I worked around it by generating the entire document in one single paragraph for formatting purposes, then broke it in separate paragraphs...