# Conditional paragraph formatting in docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to make a script for google docs that would do something like this:

Open specified document, search the text for certain word(s), and format as bold the paragraphs that **start** with those words. Adding a simple input box would be awesome too.

I've found some examples for auto-highlighting certain words ([Can I color certain words in Google Document using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064972/can-i-color-certain-words-in-google-document-using-google-script)), but I'm a complete coding dummy and can't work my way to bold paragraphs.

Or maybe there's already an add-on for that kind of things?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!