# Google Apps Script: How do I change text in a Google Doc without altering the formatting of that text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In Google Apps Script, how do I change text in a Google Doc without altering the formatting of that text?

For example, suppose I have some text like this: "The *quick* **brown** fox". And I want to change "quick" to "slow" and "brown" to "pink", but in all cases I want the format to be maintained, so that it comes out like "The *slow* **pink** fox". How can I do that in the general case?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064972/can-i-color-certain-words-in-google-document-using-google-apps-script/16924466#16924466)?

Comment: Thanks, but that changes the formatting on existing text. It doesn't change existing text while keeping the formatting, which is what I want to do.

Comment: Before replacing the text, store its format to a temporary variable. And after replacing, set its format with the temporary variable.

Comment: This would work, except that there seems to be a bug in Google Apps Script (last I checked) that prevents you from either setting or reading all format information (I can't remember which).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the [replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) method, which preserves the formatting of the text.

This example uses [Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body), but the [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) class also has the same method:

```
function changeTextButKeepFormat() {
  let body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText("quick", "slow");
  body.replaceText("brown", "pink");
}
```