# How to change a custom color in a google doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I *change* an existing custom color in a gdoc?

I'm referring to the little swatches that appear in the color dialog, where there it appears one can only ADD to the custom color list, never delete or change an existing color.

Say I have 'customred' as a custom color. It appears in the custom color swatch list. I want to change 'customred' to 'customblue' across my entire document and have this color swatch change in the color dialog as well.

How can I achieve this seemingly simple task?

I don't see any reference in the API documentation related to accessing the 'custom colors' list at all.

Comment: AFAIK, this feature is not available in Apps Script. You can try using this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12072164/5995040) as your base reference, then instead of comparing text, you compare the hex value(#FF0000) of the customColor. I'm not sure it will appear in the color swatch list and color dialog. Hope this helps.