# Script to auto highlight certain words in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm looking for a simple script for a Google Docs add-on that will highlight words held in an array. I want the script to auto-highlight the words as I type. Is this simple enough?

Thanks!

Comment: CMD+F and just type...

Comment: But what if I have a list of 50 words I want it to look out for and highlight. And depending on what words they are, highlight them in different colours?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to highlight words as you type (except mentioned Ctrl+F). As for to highlight a given array of words it's possible. But how will you pass the words into a script? A simplest way is just to put these words inside the script as an array `var arr = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']`. Or it can be all words of the first paragraph. Etc. You need to decide it beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Can I color certain words in Google Document using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064972/can-i-color-certain-words-in-google-document-using-google-apps-script)

```
function highlight_words() {
  var doc   = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var words = ['one','two','three'];
  var style = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR]:'#FFFF00' };
  var pgfs  = doc.getParagraphs();

  for (var word of words) for (var pgf of pgfs) {
    var location = pgf.findText(word);
    if (!location) continue;
    var start = location.getStartOffset();
    var end = location.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    location.getElement().setAttributes(start, end, style);
  }
}
```