# Match Word that Starts and Ends with

Tags: javascript, regex

This must be somewhere... but after wasting quite a bit of time, I can't find it:
I would like to test a string matching: `"in"+ * +"ing"`.

> In other words,
>   "**in**terest**ing**" should result in `true`, whereas
>   "**in**sist" and "str**ing**" should fail.

I am only interested in testing a **single word**, with no spaces.

I know I could do this in two tests, but I really want to do it one. As always, thanks for any help.

Comment: Single-words, or arbitrary-length strings containing full-sentences?

Comment: WOW... you people are amazing... less than 8 minutes and three replies... What if the prefix and suffix are stored in variables?: a = in; b = ing;

Comment: That's already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371565/can-you-create-javascript-regexes-on-the-fly-using-string-variables

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but that seems to be replacement.  I only want to have variables in the regular expression.

Comment: It's explicitly how to create regular expressions dynamically; *use the RegExp* outside of the `replace()` where the people *here* have shown you where to use the regular expression literal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am still pretty confused.  I have done lots of string comparison work in the past in other languages and have written simple functions that handled complex patterns (and perhaps my previous baggage is the problem).  What's the best I can read on the subject? Thanks...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you specifically want to match words then try something like this:

```
/in[a-z]*ing/i
```

If you want "in" followed by any characters at all followed by "ing" then:

```
/in.*ing/i
```

The `i` after the second `/` makes it case insensitive. Either way replace the `*` with `+` if you want to have at least one character in between "in" and "ing"; `*` matches zero or more.

Given a variable in a string you could use the regex to test for a match like this:

```
var str = "Interesting";
if (/in[a-z]*ing/i.test(str)) {
    // we have a match
}
```

**UPDATE**

> *"What if the prefix and suffix are stored in variables?"*

Well then instead of using a regex literal as shown above you'd use [`new RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and pass a string representing the pattern.

```
var prefix = "in",
    suffix = "ing",
    re = new RegExp(prefix + "[a-z]*" + suffix, "i");
if (re.match("Interesting")) {
    // we have a match
}
```

All of the regular expressions I've shown so far will match the "in" something "ing" pattern anywhere within a larger string. If the idea is to test whether the entire string matches that mattern such that "interesting" would be a match but "noninterestingstuff" would not (as per stackunderflow's comment) then you need to match the start and end of the string with `^` and `$`:

```
/^in[a-z]*ing$/i
```

Or from variables:

```
new RegExp("^" + p + "[a-z]*" + s + "$", "i")
```

Or if you're testing the whole string you don't necessarily need regex (although I find regex simpler):

```
var str = "Interesting",
    prefix = "in",
    suffix = "ing";
str = str.toLowerCase(); // if case is not important

if (str.indexOf(prefix)===0 && str.endsWith(suffix)){
   // match do something
}
```

Or for browsers that don't support [.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith):

```
if (str.slice(0,prefix.length)===prefix && str.slice(-suffix.length)===suffix)
```

> *"What's the best I can read on the subject?"*

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) gives a rundown of regex for JavaScript. [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) gives a more general set of tutorials.

Comment: matches noninterestingstuff too:
/in[a-z]*ing/i.test("noninterestingstuff")
true

Comment: @stackunderflow - Yes. For some reason I thought the OP was searching for a match within a larger string, not testing whether the whole string matched the pattern.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a masochist, but I just read http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10
It also points you towards Perl 5, e.g. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Version-8-Regular-Expressions

Answer (score 5):

```
/in.+ing/ // a string that has `in` then at least one character, then `ing`


/in.+ing/.test('interesting'); // true
/in.+ing/.test('insist');      // false
/in.+ing/.test('string');      // false

/in.+ing/.test('ining'); // false, .+ means at least one character is required.
/in.*ing/.test('ining'); // true, .* means zero or more characters are allowed.
```

If you wanted to constrain things to just one word, you could use the `\w` word character shorthand.

```
/in\w+ing/.test('invents tiring') // false, space is not a "word" character.
/in.+ing/.test('invents tiring') // true, dot matches any character, even space
```

Comment: That also returns `true` for `invents tiring`.

Comment: It would, but I don't know what the input really is here... That might be a problem and it might not! One thing at a time.

Comment: That's true; I had assumed (from his demonstrations of what should 'return true' and so forth) that he was looking for single-words, rather than strings. But it is ambiguous as written.

Comment: (Out of curiosity, and just a suggestion, but how about `/in[^\b]+ing/` to guarantee single words?)

Comment: [^\b] in a character class matches backspace.

Comment: Great answer! Simple and usable.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're looking for is `/in.*ing/` (this includes all characters).

If you're more interested in single words, use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `/in[a-z]*ing/`

You can add the `i` flag if you're not interested in case.

Comment: So... if I had two variables, prefix and suffix, where prefix = "in" and suffix = "ing", then re = new RegExp(prefix + "[a-z]*" + suffix);, upon re.test(toBeTested) would give me what I am looking for?  Sorry I am so confused... Thanks...

Comment: Correct.  If you want to create a regex out of variables, you'll need to use the `new RegExp()` format instead of forward slashes.

Comment: So what did you settle on, @nas ?
You should accept one of the answers eventually or point out remaining problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend matching word boundary as well.

Here's a fully parameterized version:

**Code**

```
(function(prefix, suffix, anchored, flags) {
    var tests = [
        "noninterestingtypo",
        "mining",
        "in8ping",
        "interesting"];
    var re = new RegExp(
    (anchored ? '\\b' : '') + prefix + '[a-z]+' + suffix + (anchored ? '\\b' : ''), flags);
    var reportMatch = function(value) {
        console.log(value.match(re) ? value + " matches" : value + " does not match");
    };
    tests.forEach(reportMatch);
})( /* prefix, suffix, anchored, flags */
    "in", "ing", true, "i");
```

**Output**

```
noninterestingtypo does not match
mining does not match
in8ping does not match
interesting matches
```

Just expand the test string array and see what happens without the `\b`.

Comment: This is a test-case, just so the -1-er understands

Answer (score 0):

If `in` in the first rule can be part of `ing` (the second rule) use

```js
/\b(?=in)(?=\w*ing\b)\w+/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/N293Vl/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    in                       'in'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ing                      'ing'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

If `in` can't be part of `ing` use

```js
/\bin\w*ing\b/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/N293Vl/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  in                       'in'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ing                      'ing'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

*JavaScript**:

```js
const string = 'interesting,ing and bing.';
const rx_1 = /\b(?=in)(?=\w*ing\b)\w+/g;
const rx_2 = /\bin\w*ing\b/g;
console.log(string.match(rx_1));
console.log(string.match(rx_2));
```