# jQuery Regex from String

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following Regex that comes from a data Attribute on an HTML Element:

```
/^$|^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}$/g
```

When I (manually) do:

```
/^$|^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}$/g.test('01.2012');
```

It works and returns `true`.

When I put the Regex in a Variable like so:

```
var inputRegex = $(this).attr('data-validation');
```

And do:

```
inputRegex.test(input);
```

I get:

> inputRegex.test is not a function.

I know that this is because inputRegex is a String and String does not have a test function, but when I create a RegExp object (`new RegExp($(this).attr('data-validation')`) it breaks my Regular Expression by escaping:

```
/\/^$|^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}$\/g/
```

How can I use the data-attribute value as a Regular Expression? Please note that I cannot do: `var regex = new RegExp(string, 'g');` because the Regular Expression(s) come predefined from the attribute.

Comment: You should not use `/g` with `RegExp.test`.

Comment: When you read value from `data-validation`, it is read as string. You can refer following link for [how to create regex from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371565/can-you-create-javascript-regexes-on-the-fly-using-string-variables)

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = '\d+';
var regExp = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
'1234dasf13241234'.match(regExp)
```

is it what you need?

```
var pattern = $(this).attr('data-validation');;
var regExp = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
regExp.test(input);
```

in your case

Comment: I have to use the Regex as it comes from the attribute, as I have no control over that part. So I cannot create the Object the way you are suggesting.

Comment: Check updated answer. I didn't see difference -- you can create callback? or which lib do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This could help

```
var validation =  "/^$|^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}$/g"; //$(this).attr('data-validation')
var startIndex = validation.indexOf('/')+1
var lastIndex = validation.lastIndexOf('/');
var pattern = validation.substring(startIndex,lastIndex);
var options = validation.substring(lastIndex+1);
var regExp = new RegExp(pattern, options);
regExp.test('01.2012');
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you need to retrieve the regex pattern from a attribute of an element, but it is returning **string**, and you want the string value to be like **inline** on your javascript code, like declaring plainly a regex. If this is really what you want to achieve, the closest solution is to use **eval** function, see updated code below:

```
var stringreg = "var inputRegex =" + $("#test").attr('data-validation') + ";"
eval(stringreg);
inputRegex.test(input);
```