# Check if a string contains any element of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can I check if a string contains any element of an array? I want to filter some array if the element has some string. Please see below code.

```js
var arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];

function checker(value) {
  var prohibited = ['banana', 'apple'];

  for (var i = 0; i < prohibited.length; i++) {
    if (value.indexOf(prohibited[i]) == -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

arr = arr.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

The result is `[ 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange' ]`. The `'apple'` should get removed, but it isn't.

Above code only filtered 'banana', not 'apple'. I have many keywords to filter. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Problem lies in the for loop, which only iterates once since return ends the function, cutting off the for loop in the process. So, you can update the code like so to make the function only return once the for loop has been completed .

```js
var arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];

function checker(value) {
  var prohibited = ['banana', 'apple'];

  for (var i = 0; i < prohibited.length; i++) {
    if (value.indexOf(prohibited[i]) > -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

arr = arr.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

---

For reducing the function you can use **[`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** and **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof)** methods

> The 'every' method executes the provided callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a falsy value (a value that becomes false when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns false. Otherwise, if callback returned a true value for all elements, every will return true. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.(*[Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)*)

```js
var arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];

function checker(value) {
  var prohibited = ['banana', 'apple'];
  return prohibited.every(function(v) {
    return value.indexOf(v) == -1;
  });
}

arr = arr.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

---

For older browser [check polyfill option of every method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill).

---

You could even use a regex here. Generate regex using the array and use **[`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** to check match

```js
var arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];

function checker(value) {
  var prohibited = ['banana', 'apple'];
  var regex = new RegExp(prohibited.map(function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
  }).join('|'));
  return !regex.test(value);
}

arr = arr.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

Refer this answer for string to regex conversion : [Can you create JavaScript regexes on the fly using string variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371565/can-you-create-javascript-regexes-on-the-fly-using-string-variables/4371855#4371855)

Answer (score 85):

It can be as simple as that:

```js
const arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];

const checker = value =>
  !['banana', 'apple'].some(element => value.includes(element));

console.log(arr.filter(checker));
```

ECMAScript 6 FTW!

The `checker` uses [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

The `!` means that it will exclude all elements that doesn't meet the conditions.

> The **`some()`** method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

<sub>from [`Array.prototype.some()` docs on MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)</sub>

> The **`includes()`** method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

<sub>from [`String.prototype.includes()` docs on MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)</sub>

---

As some latest ECMAScript features aren't supported in all browsers, you should use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code to ECMAScript 5.

Comment: How to do this with an array of numbers? am getting "value.includes is not a function" for an array of numbers. Also gives same error for value.indexOf(..) != -1

Answer (score 33):

You can use [`some()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): to check if a string contains any element of an array.

e.g.

```js
var fruitsArr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];
var myString = "I have an apple and a watermelon.";
var stringIncludesFruit = fruitsArr.some(fruit => myString.includes(fruit));
```

This function is pretty new. `some()` method accepts a callback where you define the condition you want to verify and it returns a boolean. Check the documentation at the link above.

Comment: This was my favourite of the answers for being well written and easier to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For someone looking for simple, single-liner:

```
arr.filter(item => !prohibited.some(prohb => item.includes(prohb)))  // ["kiwi", "orange"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this can be greatly simplified. There is already a built in within javascript for checking these things. Consider:

```
var arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];

function checker(value) {
  var prohibited = ['banana', 'apple'];

  // indexOf() returns -1 if the element doesn't exist in the prohibited array
  return prohibited.indexOf( value ) == -1;
}

arr = arr.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approad doesn't work the same way as the original. Please note that in the original, the comparison is made with *String.prototype.indexOf()*, but this uses *Array.prototype.indexOf()*.

In essence, in the original, for the second element of `arr`, the monkey banana, it calls `'monkey banana'.indexOf('banana')`, which returns 7 (and then a second call for the second element of `prohibited`). In your example, it calls `['banana', 'apple'].indexOf('monkey banana')`, which returns -1.

Answer (score 4):

Some may argue that this is a questionable practice, but you may find it useful to have a method that you can run on the string directly - in which case you could extend the JavaScript [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object using [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype).

**Like this...**

```js
String.prototype.containsAny = String.prototype.containsAny || function(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (this.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

As you can see in this example, it will default to any existing definition of a `containsAny` method. Keep in mind: any time you're augmenting built-in objects, it's a good idea to at least check for the presence of the property first – perhaps some day it will exist...
**¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Check out [this fiddle](https://cdn.simpledigital.net/fiddles/js/fiddle-javascript.prototype.containsAny.html#Result) for usage or **see below**:

```js
var str = 'This is a sentence as a string.';

console.log(str.containsAny(['string1', 'string2', 'string3'])); // -> returns false
console.log(str.containsAny(['string', 'string1', 'string2'])); // -> returns true
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.simpledigital.net/common/js/extensions/String.prototypeHelpers.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    const stringInput = "I have a kiwi";
    const arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];
    const exists = arr.some((t) => stringInput.indexOf(t) > -1); 
or
    const exists = arr.some((t) => stringInput.includes(t)); 
// iterate through arr items.
// If any of your item is a substring in the input string, then the result of the statement will be `true` otherwise will be `false`.
```

For `some` function please check this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

For `includes` function please check this reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For example by building a RegExp and testing against that:

```
var arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];
var prohibited = ['banana', 'apple'];

var escapeForRegex = function(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
};

var r = new RegExp(prohibited.map(escapeForRegex).join("|"));
arr.filter(function(v){ return !r.test(v) });
```