# Compare strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, compare

I need to compare titles (which are made of many words)
with a list of bad words. For one word, indexOf works fine.
but when there are many swear words it doesn't.

Can anyone help with this?

```
var title = "This is my title";
var badwordlist = title.indexOf('fword and other bad words list');
//var badwordlist = title.indexOf('fword');

if ( badwordlist >= 0){
//do something 
}
```

Comment: Loop over your title and use badwords.indexOf(titleword[i]) instead of the other way around

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string contains any element of an array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428338/check-if-a-string-contains-any-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the two answers posted so far are overdoing things

```js
var title = "fword This is a f**king title.",
  words = title.split(" "),
  badwords = ["fword", "f**king"];

// one of these should do it    

var isGood = words.filter(function(a) {
  return badwords.indexOf(a) == -1;
});

var isBad = words.filter(function(a) {
  return badwords.indexOf(a) != -1;
});

console.log(isBad, isGood);

// if isBad.length>0 then there were swear words in the title
```

Comment: Thanks! but what i need is not to filter out bad words. The only thing I need is to detect badwords and return true or false. how can i do that?

Comment: `return isBad.length>0`

Comment: you are a genius ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.includes()` to check if the string contains the bad word:

```js
var title = "fword This is title.";
var badwords = ["fword", "f**k"];

var isbad = badwords.map(function(a) {
  return title.includes(a);
});

console.log(isbad);
```

Comment: Oh! thanks @mplungjan yes string.includes also do it.

Comment: Jai, this is the closest thing to what I want. I need a true or false.  But how come isbad always returns false?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution, which involves an array, a cycle and a function which coordinates these

```
var badwords = ['fword', 'uglyword'];
var replacements = ['*word', 'ug***ord'];
function replaceBadwords(title) {
    for (var badwordIndex in badwords) {
        if (title.indexOf(badwords[badwordIndex]) >= 0) {
            title = title.split(badwords[badwordIndex]).join(replacements[badwordIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the word 'assignment' contains an ugly word, which in fact is not ugly. I mean if you read only the first three characters, you will think this is an ugly word. To cope with these exceptions make sure you will not censor these as well.

Answer (score -1):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428338/check-if-a-string-contains-any-element-of-an-array-in-javascript). This will do:

```js
var arr = ['banana', 'monkey banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'orange'];

function checker(value) {
  var prohibited = ['banana', 'apple'];

  for (var i = 0; i < prohibited.length; i++) {
    if (value.indexOf(prohibited[i]) > -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

arr = arr.filter(checker);
console.log(arr);
```

Obtain arr by splitting your title on space, eg `title.split(" ")`.

Once you do any filtering you can create a filtered title with `title = arr.join(" ")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that my title is not the same everytime. how can I store it in an array?
var title = "This is my title";

var title = tab.title;

Comment: Did you read the whole answer? At the end it says Obtain arr by splitting your title on space, eg `title.split(" ")`

Comment: once you do any filtering you can create the title again with `arr.join(" ")`

Comment: Ok will try this. Thanks !

Comment: I don't think you understand that strings are arrays themselves and can be checked using `indexOf`

Comment: Why are you filtering using a function that is looping? That seems like overkill

Comment: a string only indexOf will tell you if the prohibited word is in the title, true, but this way he can filter it as well.

Comment: See what I mean in my answer

Comment: fair enough the other is more concise yes