# filter in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider an array A1 `["text", "test"]` and another array A2 `["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"]`

I need to get the result as `["onetest", "threetext", "fourtext"]`

This is what I currently have

```
A2.filter(r => r !== null && A1.indexOf(r) > -1);
```

This is returning empty list. How do I fix that?

Comment: And why should (e.g.) `"onetest"` be part of `A1`? The elements of `A1` have to be part of `r`.

Comment: There's nothing in common between `A1` and `A2`. Unless you're trying to filter by substring perhaps?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to filter by substring

Comment: You may want to read the answers to [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4556099/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string contains any element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428338/check-if-a-string-contains-any-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `r` is a string, therefore `r.text` is neither necessary nor correct.
2. `A1.indexOf(r) > -1` checks if the string `r` is included in the array `A1`. This is not true for any of your items.

Instead of `r.text`, just use `r`. To determine if the string `r` contains any of the substrings in `A1`, you can use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const A1 = ["text", "test"];
const A2 = ["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"];

const result = A2.filter(r => r !== null && A1.some(a => r.includes(a)));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! What if A1: object[] = {[id: 1, name:"text"], [id:2, name: "test"]} and another array A2 ["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"] and return result ["onetest", "threetext", "fourtext"]?

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues: first, the elements of `A2` do not have a property called `text`, so `r.text` is `undefined` and you probably just want to use `r` instead.

Second, `A1.indexOf` is not what you want. `indexOf` is both an array method and a string method, and I think you're confusing them. The array method is used to find the index of an exact match, whereas the string method can be used to find the location of a substring. What you want is to determine whether *any* member of `A1` is present as a substring in the given member of `A2`. I suggest the `Array.prototype.some` method, which determines whether a given predicate is true for *any* member of an array. Within this we can create a predicate using the string method `indexOf`.

See if this works for you:

```js
const A1 = ["text", "test"]
const A2 = ["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"]

// I need to get the result as ["onetest", "threetext", "fourtext"]

console.log(A2.filter(r => r !== null && A1.some(s => r.indexOf(s) > -1)))
```

Comment: Thank you! What if A1: object[] = {[id: 1, name:"text"], [id:2, name: "test"]} and another array A2 ["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"] and return result ["onetest", "threetext", "fourtext"]?

Answer (score 2):

You could filter by checking each value of the pattern string.

```js
var a1 = ["text", "test"],
    a2 = ["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"],
    result = a2.filter(s => a1.some(p => s.includes(p)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! What if A1: object[] = {[id: 1, name:"text"], [id:2, name: "test"]} and another array A2 ["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"] and return result ["onetest", "threetext", "fourtext"]?

Comment: then take `a2.filter(({ name }) => a1.some(p => name.includes(p)))`.

Answer (score 0):

`A1.indexOf(r)` only checks if an element of the array matches **exactly** the given text, and is not the case, you're searching for a substring.

Try with this:

```js
var a1 = ["text", "test"];
var a2 = ["onetest", "two", "threetext", "fourtext"];

var filtered = a2.filter( e => a1.some( e2 => e.indexOf( e2 ) != -1 ) );
console.log( filtered );
```

This will filter the second array checking for each element if the string contains some of the first array element.