# How do I block NSFW urls from being entered?

Tags: javascript

How would I make it so if someone tries to submit and open a NSFW site it either takes them to a custom block page that I can make or just not submit?

```js
$('unblocker-form').onsubmit = function() {
  var url = $('url').value;
  if (url.substr(0, 4) != "http") {
    url = "http://" + url;
  }
  window.location.pathname = 'p/' + url;
  return false;

};
```

```html
<form align="center" action="no-js" method="get" id="unblocker-form">
  <p>
    URL:
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url" placeholder="EXP: coolmathgames.com      " />
    <input type="submit" id="btnCheck" onclick="fnCheckForRestrictedWords();" value="Go" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: It's simple - just get a list of every single NSFW URL in existence, then check the entered URL against it.

Comment: Who gets to decide whether a link is NSFW? There might be restricted words in the link to a perfectly innocuous site (like https://www.scunthorpe-united.co.uk/) or an innocuous-seeming URL that goes to a totally inappropriate site (you can find these yourself).

Comment: First thing you'll need is a list of restricted words. Then you'll need to [check if the URL contains any of those restricted words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37428338/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think we've tried the restricted words [and it doesn't really work very well](http://www.romansinsussex.co.uk/)

Comment: @VLAZ Wasn't commenting on whether the request was rationally feasible overall, just on the immediate task. Note that getting a list of restricted words that works when used in substring matching is the part that I skipped over :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have a .txt file with 13k P*rn sites that I want to filter out of my unblocker form but not sure how.