# Need JS array negative filter based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need help on filtering a Javascript array to remove names that DO NOT include at least one of a series of letters listed in a second array. I have tried over and over, using combinations of filter(), and also nested FOR loops. EXAMPLE:

name = ["chuck","lina","wanda","denise","reggie","candy"];
letter = ["h","l","z","e"];

The array returned by filter() should be:
nametwo = ["wanda","candy"];

It's simple to explain but I just cannot make it work in code. I've found many examples of filter() on here but none has helped. Thanks!

Comment: HI all - thanks for your responses.  All good... <3<3<3 you all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37434514/13583510)

```js
const name = ["chuck","lina","wanda","denise","reggie","candy"];
const letter = ["h","l","z","e"];

const checker = value =>
  !letter.some(element => value.includes(element));

console.log(name.filter(checker));
```

Answer (score 1):

For searching letters inside a string, you should use indexOf function.

If you want one line solution you can do it this way:

```js
const names = ["chuck","lina","wanda","denise","reggie","candy"];
const letters = ["h","l","z","e"];
const result = names.filter(name => letters.filter(letter => name.indexOf(letter) !== -1).length === 0);

console.log(result)
```

And you can do it use two cycles:

```js
const names = ["chuck","lina","wanda","denise","reggie","candy"];
const letters = ["h","l","z","e"];

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    let isContainLetter = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
      if (names[i].indexOf(letters[j]) !== -1) {
        isContainLetter = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  if (!isContainLetter) result.push(names[i]);
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it explains the logic, not just provides code.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter with `every` and check if the name does not contains letters.

```js
const
    names = ["chuck", "lina", "wanda", "denise", "reggie", "candy"],
    letters = ["h", "l", "z", "e"],
    result = names.filter(n => letters.every(l => !n.includes(l)));

console.log(result); // ["wanda", "candy"]
```

Comment: Brilliant, absolutely brilliant. Works like a charm. Wow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use **:**

- [Array.every()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to test whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function or not. It returns a Boolean value.
- Then we can use [Array.filter()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method which creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const name = ["chuck","lina","wanda","denise","reggie","candy"];
const letter = ["h","l","z","e"];

const resultArr = name.filter((word) => letter.every((char) => !word.includes(char)));

console.log(resultArr);
```