# Determine if a string contains any of an array of characters

Tags: javascript

If I have a number of characters (either as a string or an array), does JavaScript have a function to tell me if any of those characters appear within a string?

For example, given the following, I want a function that returns true because `str` does contain one of the characters in `chars`.

```
const chars = [ '[', ']', '{', '}' ];
var str = "BlahBlah}";
```

In C#, I can use `IndexOfAny()`, but I'm not finding a similar function in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `includes()` method, nothing you have to loop over each char in the array and use the `includes` function on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript)

Comment: or [Check if a string contains any element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428338/check-if-a-string-contains-any-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @pilchard: That isn't the same at all.

Comment: It is identical and the 12 year old [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582621/13762301) is the same as the one you accepted here `substrings.some(v => str.includes(v))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
const chars = [ '[', ']', '{', '}' ];
const str = "BlahBlah}";

const result = chars.some(x=>str.includes(x))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 automates looping through arrays with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Try:

```
substrings.some(function(v) { return str.indexOf(v) >= 0; })
```

Or, to prototype this to String yourself (not recommend):

```
String.prototype.indexOfAny = function(arr) {
    return arr.some(function(v) { return str.indexOf(v) >= 0; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reusable Functional Approach

```js
const chars = [ '[', ']', '{', '}' ];
const str = "BlahBlah}";

const chars2 = [ '[', ']', '{', '}' ];
const str2 = "Amoos";


const findStringInArray = (string, array) => array.some( arr =>string.includes(arr) )


console.log( findStringInArray(str, chars) )



console.log( findStringInArray(str2, chars2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

JS contains metod includes. For example:

```
const chars = [ '[', ']', '{', '}' ];
var str = "BlahBlah}";

for (const i of str) {
  if (chars.includes(i)) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).