# Javascript: Is it possible to append regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, is it possible to append a regular expression to another? I know it is possible to combine two regular expressions with OR, but I am referring to appending two regular expressions into one (more of an AND), similar to how you would do string arithmetic.

For example, this is what I would want:

```
var postfix = /don't know/    
var x = /I / + postfix        // would now become /I don't know/
var y = /You / + postfix      // would now become /You don't know/
```

What I am trying to do is reduce the amount of places I would need to hardcode `postfix` while still preserving `I` and `You`, which is why something like `/(I|You) don't know/` wouldn't work.

Comment: You can just access the `.source` of the regex object to get the pattern text. E.g. `var x = new RegExp('I ' + postfix.source)`

Comment: Why not concatenate strings and _then_ turn them into regexes, when you have the final form?

Comment: ^^ or that, if you never use `postfix` directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you create JavaScript regexes on the fly using string variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371565/can-you-create-javascript-regexes-on-the-fly-using-string-variables)

Comment: @jonrsharpe (shrug) Sort of duplicate because I can see what I was looking for in the question you linked, but only after reading and understanding the answer given to me in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.source`:

```js
var postfix = /don't know/    
var x = new RegExp(/I /.source + postfix.source) 

console.log(x)
//=> /I don't know/

var y = new RegExp(/You /.source + postfix.source)
console.log(y)
//=> /You don't know/
```

Comment: Why would you write `/You /.source`, as opposed to... `'You '`?

Comment: Because I believe OP already had 2 regex that need to be added into a single regex