# Build Javascript regex that expects the first character to be capitalized, case insensitive for the rest

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a large list of job skills, like you might see on LinkedIn ("Nuclear Physics", "Python", "Heavy Machinery", etc). I also have a large block of text: a job description. I am trying to iterate through the list and identify which skills are present in the block of text. Here is my current code:

```js
  // escape possible special characters in a string
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371565/
  const escapeRegExp = (s) => {
    return s.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
  }

  let skills_in_job = {}

  skills.forEach(skill => {
    // Creating a regexp to search for all instances of <skill>
    // \b means it is a standalone word (to prevent 'React' being in 'Reactive')
    // 'g' means it will search globally (not just the first it finds)
    // 'i' means it will be case insensitive
    // Add word boundaries to make sure it is not a substring of a word
    const rx = RegExp("\\b" + escapeRegExp(skill) + "\\b", 'gi')
    const count = (job.match(rx) || []).length
    if (count) skills_in_job[skill] = count
  })
```

However, the `i` flag is giving me some issues:

- It fails to avoid false positives("React" the framework vs "react to")
- A job can have multiple capitalizations of the same thing (Reactjs/ReactJS, Styled Components/Styled components)

Ideally, my regex expression should care only about capitalization of the first letter. I am not sure how to do this programatically.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to define a regexp in JS that's only partially case insensitive. It can be done with PCRE using `(?i)` before the insensitive part, but that doesn't work in JS.

Comment: So you need to change your keywords to something like `R[Ee][Aa][Cc][Tt]`

Comment: Regular expressions are probably not the appropriate tool for natural language processing like this.

Comment: `function ucfirst(string){ const s = string.split(''), f = s.shift().toUpperCase(); return f+s.join(''); }`

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. I will look into NLP with javascript if my use case becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript regex does not support inline modifiers (`(?i)`), nor modifier groups (`(?i:...)`).

You may either follow the path suggested by Barmar and create a character class out of each non-initial letter and then build a case sensitive regex:

```
skill = skill.replace(/\B./g, (x) => `[${x.toLowerCase()}${x.toUpperCase()}]`);
const rx = RegExp("\\b" + escapeRegExp(skill) + "\\b", 'g');
```

Or, you may simply filter out the matches that start with a different case of the first letter

```
const rx = RegExp("\\b" + escapeRegExp(skill) + "\\b", 'gi')
const matches = (job.match(rx) || []).filter(x => x.charAt(0) == skill.charAt(0));
const count = (matches || []).length;
```

Comment: Wow, the suggestions given far exceeded my expectations. I think for now now I will stick with the simple first letter check (very elegant), but I appreciate the overview of the thought process behind it.